# Add property to couchdb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, couchdb, couchrest

I have setup an `couchdb` database to be used with a `ruby on rails` application using [couchrest](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest).

Now the database has around 100K records and I want to add a field to store timestamp in integer format.
Trying to update it in a loop through causes request time out.

What is the best way to add a new field/property to the couchdb ?

**Code**

```
pages = Page.all
pages.each do |p|
  p.update_attributes(:created_at_to_i => p.created_at.to_i)
  puts p.created_at_to_i.inspect
end
```

**Trace**

```
>> Page.update_timestamp
RestClient::RequestTimeout: Request Timeout
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:184:in `transmit'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:64:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/request.rb:33:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/couchrest-1.1.2/lib/couchrest/rest_api.rb:89:in `execute'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/couchrest-1.1.2/lib/couchrest/rest_api.rb:45:in `get'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/couchrest-1.1.2/lib/couchrest/database.rb:260:in `view'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/couchrest-1.1.2/lib/couchrest/design.rb:52:in `view_on'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/couchrest_model-1.1.2/lib/couchrest/model/views.rb:142:in `fetch_view'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/couchrest_model-1.1.2/lib/couchrest/model/views.rb:135:in `fetch_view_with_docs'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/couchrest_model-1.1.2/lib/couchrest/model/views.rb:104:in `view'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/couchrest_model-1.1.2/lib/couchrest/model/document_queries.rb:12:in `all'
    from /var/www/monitoring_couch/app/models/page.rb:309:in `update_timestamp'
    from (irb):2
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a new property you need to load each document, modify it, and save it back to the database. You could do it using the [bulk update api](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Bulk_Document_API), but for just 100k I would think it's not worth the extra hassle.

Please post your update script and the traceback you get when the timeout occurs.